# Mysql query error when using ">" operator

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get output from mysql database as JSON. There is a problem in my code. Problem is if i put 0,1,2,3 or 4 to here **tbl_stock.qty> ?** ,No output is given. But if I put 5 or higher number than 5 it gives me the output.

**My php code**

```
<?php
     require_once 'include/Configg.php';
     header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("connection failed");
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$con) or die("db selection failed");

        $r=mysql_query("select tbl_stock.matnum, tbl_stock.sorg, tbl_stock.qty, tbl_mas_material.matname, tbl_mas_material.matgrp from tbl_stock INNER JOIN tbl_mas_material on tbl_stock.matnum = tbl_mas_material.matnum where tbl_stock.qty> 0");

        $result = array();

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
            array_push($result,
            array('matnum'=>$row[0],
           'sorg'=>$row[1],'qty'=>$row[2],'matname'=>$row[3],'matgrp'=>$row[4]));}

            echo json_encode(array("feed"=>$result));


        mysql_close($con); 

    ?>
```

Comment: your `tbl_stock.qty` may be all containing the value greater than 5.

Comment: share tbl_stock table schema...

Comment: Add space between `tbl_stock.qty`and `0` It would be `tbl_stock.qty > 0`

Comment: run your sql directly via some mysql client or console and see output. if resultset is empty, most probably there is no records with qty < 5.

Comment: mysql will treat this `tbl_stock.qty>` as a column name....

Comment: @FrayneKonok then if i use greater than 0, there need to have an output.

Comment: @mitkosoft I ran it in the mysql workbench and it gave me the output. I don't know why this isn't work. 748 rows returned

Comment: @ZafarMalik here is the schema..

CREATE TABLE `tbl_stock` (
  `matnum` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `sorg` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`matnum`,`sorg`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: print     $row     inside while loop & check what it returns . Also  qty should be `int` not `varchar`.

Comment: the problem occure when i put **tbl_mas_material.matname** . if i remove **tbl_mas_material.matname** and put 0 then it gives me the out put from the query

Answer (score 0):

Use **LEFT JOIN** in your query. The **LEFT JOIN** keyword returns all rows from the left table (tbl_stock), with the matching rows in the right table (tbl_mas_material).

The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

```
SELECT tbl_stock.matnum, tbl_stock.sorg, tbl_stock.qty, tbl_mas_material.matname, tbl_mas_material.matgrp 
FROM tbl_stock 
LEFT JOIN tbl_mas_material 
ON tbl_stock.matnum = tbl_mas_material.matnum 
WHERE tbl_stock.qty > 0
```

Also as suggested by *[saty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4662759/saty)*, **add space** between tablename and '>' operator. write it as `tbl_stock.qty > 0`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding your query should be ok. Try it in a console, but you should be allowed to skip the space before the > operator and clearly if some rows match for ">5" they should match also for ">0".

I suspect your problem is not in the query: my guess is that you have a row in table tbl_stock with qty = 4 that give you problems when you build the output array.

Add some error handling in your code and output some intermediate results to check the data and how the output is build.

Answer (score 0):

**problem:**

qty field should be integer type instead of varchar.

**Solution:**

Best way is to change it integer but if you don't want to do it due to some specific reasons then use below query-

```
SELECT tbl_stock.matnum, tbl_stock.sorg, tbl_stock.qty, tbl_mas_material.matname, tbl_mas_material.matgrp 
FROM tbl_stock INNER 
JOIN tbl_mas_material ON tbl_stock.matnum = tbl_mas_material.matnum 
WHERE CAST(tbl_stock.qty AS UNSIGNED) > 0
```

Comment: not working brother. I can't edit the table. I am not authorized to do that. This code give output in mysql workbench very well. 752 rows are giving. I don't know why this isn't working in my php file. Is too much data to process??

Comment: may be it will provide you results but as a standard you can't compare varchar values as numeric...further you can do that first create an index on qty field and enclose zero as '0'..i.e. where qty > '0' and check

Comment: but if you get correct results then after creating index use cast function as i suggested in my answer.

Comment: the problem occure when i put **tbl_mas_material.matname** . if i remove **tbl_mas_material.matname** and put 0 then it gives me the out put from the query

Comment: also show output of "show create table tbl_mas_material;"

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbl_mas_material` (
  `matnum` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `matname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `matgrp` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mattype` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`matnum`,`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: even **"SELECT tbl_mas_material.matname from tbl_mas_material"** is not giving an output. issue occurred with **matname**